# Cannot read the property in the typescript in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a static array in the class in typescipt. But I couldn't read its property.

The error is shown below.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forbiddenProjectNames' of undefined
```

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```
export class CustomValidator {

  private static forbiddenProjectNames = ['Test'];

  static forbiddenNames(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (this.forbiddenProjectNames.indexOf(control.value) !== -1) {
      return { 'nameIsForbidden': true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you mark the property and the method as `static`? At least for the property it does not make sense, because you mark it as private anyway, so you don't want to instatiate it from outside.

Comment: your code is working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnxev8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve it by using this

```
 static forbiddenNames(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (CustomValidator.forbiddenProjectNames.indexOf(control.value) !== -1) {
      return { 'projectNameIsForbidden': true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You marked it as `static`, so you can refer to it like this: `CustomValidator.forbiddenProjectNames`

Comment: its working fine in even if he use this keyword https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnxev8